# How to upgrade Android kernel version

Tags: updates, linux, kernel

I am running a Android device with a kernel version of 3.4.5 on a soc made by mediatek (MT6582). Now recently I found a within post with the stock untouched KitKat based kernel for MT6582. This new KitKat kernel is version 3.4.67 I believe. And in the github page the guy mentioned a thing about upgrading the kernel version without having to necessarily make a new one. It didnt have any steps and I didn't really understand much if someone can help on how to upgrade the Linux kernel it would very very helpful.
Here is what it read:

> Unlike patches for the 3.x kernels, patches for the 3.x.y kernels
>      (also known as the -stable kernels) are not incremental but instead apply
>      directly to the base 3.x kernel.  Please read
>      Documentation/applying-patches.txt for more information.
>
> Alternatively, the script patch-kernel can be used to automate this
>      process.  It determines the current kernel version and applies any
>      patches found.
>
> ```
> linux/scripts/patch-kernel linux
> ```
>
> The first argument in the command above is the location of the
>      kernel source.  Patches are applied from the current directory, but
>      an alternative directory can be specified as the second argument.
>
> If you are upgrading between releases using the stable series patches
>      (for example, patch-3.x.y), note that these "dot-releases" are
>      not incremental and must be applied to the 3.x base tree. For
>      example, if your base kernel is 3.0 and you want to apply the
>      3.0.3 patch, you do not and indeed must not first apply the
>      3.0.1 and 3.0.2 patches. Similarly, if you are running kernel
>      version 3.0.2 and want to jump to 3.0.3, you must first
>      reverse the 3.0.2 patch (that is, patch -R) *before* applying
>      the 3.0.3 patch.

So does anyone know how I can upgrade my kernel version...if yes can you please tell me how another related info to help me would also be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The instructions you've found are for applying a patch to the *source code* of the kernel. They're only relevant if you're compiling the kernel yourself, which I guess isn't what you want. You need to find a *binary* of the kernel (i.e. a boot.img), which will probably come with instructions on how to flash it.

Answer (score 1):

I totally doubt if the kernel is for MTK devices because as per my knowledge goes (I too own a MT6582 device) MTK is a partially closed-source SoC manufacturer who gives out the source code by purchasing.
MTK makes a standard ROM based on AOSP and gives it out to companies but no companies are allowed to edit the ROM unless they buy the license for it.
This means that non-MTK associates can not make any part of the ROM as they don't have  the source-code

My Suggestion: Don't try this stunt because you may end up with a kernel with miss matching drivers and also a boot-looped device as a bonus :)

Comment: Hi also since u told me u have a mt6582 phone may I know if you are running a custom and also which version I'd your current rom... thanks

Comment: what do you mean you have to purchase the source code? You cannot, by law, use the linux kernel without providing the sources for free

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the link to the github post in the post?

I don't know a lot about to make(update) a kernel but what I do know is that it requires a lot of programming skill.

One of the major problems with mediatek SOCs is that they rarely give out the source-code for their sockets. 
This makes it even harder go build a custom kernel.

I did find one failed attempt for your socket.
 [XDA forums:[KERNEL] [3.4.5] Wiko DarkMoon (MT6582)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/wiko-darkmoon-mt6582-performance-06-08-t2840159)

Another problem is that the rom is specifically made for the linux kernel and that newer kernels might not work with your device. [Source:(stackexchange).](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47472/how-can-i-update-the-linux-kernel-of-my-android-device)

It is a lot of hassle to update the kernel and I doubt it is even remotely worth it.

Comment: Hi I have actually seen the wiki darkroom kernel before...but it isn't for my device and I'm not sure if I can port that to my phone if yes please tell me....also here is the github source....if u are veiwing the github source view it in desktop version of the page for the description thing containing the article about the upgrade.

Comment: Oops forgot to add the link here it is https://github.com/kashifmin/MT6582-KK-KERNEL/

Comment: Oops for the darkrom kernel by incompatibility I meant that I already have kernel 3.4.5 and am looking for kernel 3.4.67 which supports kitkat